# Efficient weighted sum of images in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a bunch of images that are grouped into tensor of a following shape:

```
> images.shape
```

produces `(2000, 1440, 1, 16)` which have the following meaning `(rows, cols, channels, images_count)`

Now for the sake of explanation simplicity I need to perform a weighted sum of those images that would result with one image i.e. `(2000, 1440, 1)`.

Actually there are multiple groups of weights (over 128) and this means that out of 16 input images I get 128 merged images instead of just one which judging by the image size is pretty heavy operation.

And so I'm looking for ways / ideas that would allow me to perform the operation fast and efficiently with minimal amount of temporaries and memory size consumed.

Are there any mechanisms in TF that would allow to perform this operation efficiently and fast?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please show your attempt as it will help clarify the kind of operation you're performing ?

Comment: @edkeveked what do you mean by `attempt`?

Comment: I did not really get what you're trying to do from the question. So if you can provide the code of what you're trying to do, it will help see how to simplify the operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose for simplicity that you have a 8 different groups of weights and the data is in format you have specified.

First we convert images to a conventional `batch_size` first form. Than we expand dimensions of images by adding second one to support broadcasting when we are doing element-wise multiplication between images and weights. Finally, we reduce the first dimension by computing the (already weighted) sum of images for each weight group.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2000, 1440, 1, None))
w = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2000, 1440, 1))

xtransposed = tf.transpose(x, perm=[3, 0, 1, 2]) # n_samples first
xexpanded = tf.expand_dims(xtransposed, 1) # expand for broadcasting

multiplied = xexpanded * w

reduced = tf.reduce_sum(multiplied, axis=0) # weighted sum over all images

images = np.random.normal(size=(2000, 1440, 1, 16))
weights = np.random.normal(size=(8, 2000, 1440, 1))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(reduced, feed_dict={x:images, w:weights})
    print(res.shape) # (8, 2000, 1440, 1)
```

`res` now stores weighted sums for 8 different weights groups in numpy format.